# how to achieve std:map in C++ v60?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I'm trying to implement Dictionary type operation in C++ -V60 build tools. I found map for the alternative for Dictionary generic type in C++. But while trying to implement it i'm facing issue while declaring the map variables.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // insert single values
    map<int, int> m1;
}
```

Error:

```
'std::reverse_bidirectional_iterator<std::_Tree<int,std::pair<int const ,int>,std::map<int,int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<int> >::_Kfn,std::less<int>,std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator,std::pair<int const ,int>,std::pair<int const ,int> const &,std::pair<int const ,int> const *,int>' : identifier was truncated to '255' characters in the debug information
```

Comment: That should just be a waring so you should be able to keep going. If you don't want to look at the message cluttering up your build diagnostics, add `#pragma warning(disable: <warning code number>)` up at the top of the file.

Comment: what's V60? That kind of error  could be seen in very old build chains (like pre-98 era) because of debugger limitations, but even there it was a warning.

Comment: Yeah it is a warning. But as per my project standard warnings also treated as error. So i must resolve all the warnings as well.

Comment: Visual C++6, I suspect. Sucks to have to use Cretaceous tools, but according to Thomas Wolfe, *Man is born to live, to suffer, and to die, and what befalls him is a tragic lot.*

Comment: this one can be only ignored, not disabled, if that's Visual C 6.0, if I recall right. Also there was `map` impelementation there but it had a few ifferences from ISO, being based on STL

Comment: OK. That super-sucks. Discuss that one with your manager to see if you can get an exception. It's not worth your organization's time to write your own dictionary implementation when one's already available and blocked by a a warning about reduced debugging capabilities.

Comment: @user4581301 VC60 compiler architecture was literally pre-STL (and pre-ISO standard), it wasn't ready for such constructs. It got implementation of STL based on  HP version  but even that generates those messages. Also compiler had odd operator behavior (due to pre-standard overload selection) and initialization.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I have tried those answers  STL - what is the problem of the following code? also. But I couldn't resolve my problem.

Comment: I would ask your manager a different question: Is there any reason to insist on a compiler from stone-age if state-of-the-art compilers are available for free? I know the situation with legacy code from my own business. At one point, keeping the old stuff alive is more expensive than throwing it away and write it new or, at least, maintain and modernize the code. It's not quite easy to recognize the cross-over but after 20 years or so, it should be passed. ;-)

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the compiler is way out of support from Microsoft so may and probably will contain security vulnerabilities

Comment: @Scheff - I'm guessing it's a problem as old as time. It's a legacy product with a single engineer maintaining it, high paying customers, and very few automated tests. The code probably controls a nuclear power plant. :)

Comment: Also, if you need a butt simple dictionary with an unoptimized running time, there's CAtlMap available by including `#include <atlbase.h>` and `#include <atlcoll.h>`.  I'm guessing that ATL helper class was available in VC 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable warning before including header files, e.g.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4786)
```

Warning 4786 is linker warning, so you have add something like /IGNORE:4786 to list of switches in command line